# Mount Android emulator images

Tags: android, image, emulation, mount

I am trying to analyse Android malware on an emulator with Android 2.1. I want to analyze the files permissions and fingerprints after the execution of the suspicious app. I know, I can use the `adb shell` to get this information, but I think I can't trust the information after the execution of e.g. a rootkit.

I think the only way to prevent rootkits from hiding is by mounting the images directly or?
I have the following files:

```
ramdisk.img  snapshots.img  userdata-qemu.img  cache.img  system.img  userdata.img  zImage
```

How can they be mounted/extracted on Ubuntu (read access is enough)?

With unyaffs I can extract the `system.img` and `userdata.img` file. simg2img returns "bad magic" for all files.

Thanks Alex

Edit: `userdata-qemu.img` works unyaffs2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've already answered your own question but I'll expand a bit.
The Android sdk comes with system images, for example:

```
$ cd android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-15/armeabi-v7a/
$ ls *.img
ramdisk.img  system.img  userdata.img

$ cd ~/.android/avd/<img name>.avd/
$ ls *.img
cache.img  sdcard.img  userdata.img  userdata-qemu.img
```

Though, not all images are of the same type:

```
$ file *.img
cache.img:         VMS Alpha executable
sdcard.img:        x86 boot sector, code offset 0x5a, OEM-ID "MSWIN4.1", sectors/cluster 4, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors 2048000 (volumes > 32 MB) , FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 3993, reserved3 0x800000, serial number 0x17de3f04, label: "     SDCARD"
userdata.img:      VMS Alpha executable
userdata-qemu.img: VMS Alpha executable
```

Since `sdcard.img` contains no extra partitions, it can be mounted directly without an offset parameter (like `-o loop,offset=32256`):

```
$ fdisk -l sdcard.img
You must set cylinders.
You can do this from the extra functions menu.

Disk sdcard.img: 0 MB, 0 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 0 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

$ sudo mount -o loop sdcard.img /mnt/
```

The other image files which are described as `VMS Alpha executable` are in fact [yaffs2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAFFS) files. As far as I'm aware they can't be mounted directly but can be extracted using the two utilities [unyaffs](http://code.google.com/p/unyaffs/) or [unyaffs2](http://code.google.com/p/yaffs2utils/).

```
$ mkdir extract
$ cd extract
$ unyaffs ../userdata.img
```

or

```
$ unyaffs2 --yaffs-ecclayout ../userdata.img .
```

Note, there's another utility called `simg2img` which can be found in the android source tree under `./android_src/system/extras/ext4_utils/` which is used on compressed ext4 img files. However, if wrongly applied to `yaffs2` images it complains with `Bad magic`.

Answer (score 8):

If anyone ends up here looking for more information on the use of `simg2img`:

This is the file I needed to mount:

```
$ file factoryfs.img 
factoryfs.img: data
$ unyaffs factoryfs.img 
Can't determine flash layout, perhaps not a yaffs2 image
```

And this is how I was able to mount it:

1. Install simg2img

   - On newer versions of Ubuntu it's available as a package

     ```
     sudo apt install simg2img
     ```
   - On older versions of Ubuntu you'll need to compile it from source

     1. Install prerequisites

        ```
        sudo apt install build-essential git zlib1g-dev
        ```
     2. Download and compile source

        ```
        git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core
        cd core/libsparse
        gcc -o simg2img -Iinclude simg2img.c sparse_crc32.c backed_block.c output_file.c sparse.c sparse_err.c sparse_read.c -lz
        ```
2. Uncompress the sparse image file to a raw image file:

   ```
   simg2img /path/to/factoryfs.img /path/to/factoryfs.raw.img
   ```
3. Mount the raw image file. In Ubuntu the easiest way to do this is by right-clicking the file in the Files app → **Open With** → **Disk Image Mounter**. Or using the command line:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/factoryfs
   sudo mount /path/to/factoryfs.raw.img /mnt/factoryfs
   ```

**Note:** This won't work with boot.img, which is a special case:
[How to extract boot.img?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65316/14436)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to unpack a NON-SPARSE ext4 image file on Windows.  simg2img is for use with sparse ext4.  Ext4 is not sparse by definition, that's just an option for it, yet every description of this process starts with that assumption for whatever reason.  Anyway, DiskTool did this for me with zero effort, after I wasted lots of time trying to figure this out.  It doesn't install any extraneous garbage either, and it works fine on Windows 10:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/androidicsjbext/